# Unity 3D, animation will not swap over from idle on the Bool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, character

I know my code is incorrect I am trying to simply add an animator field that focuses on when to engage the next animation from idle.

I am happy with my AWSD controls but every other code I can find online uses a different control layout and I am simply confused as to how to add a private entry on someone else's code. Guys, I am new to Unity and new to coding.

Please help!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 5.0f;


    private Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        speed = 5.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        { 
            transform.Translate(-1 * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { 
            transform.Rotate(0, -1, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
    }
        `animator.SetBool("IsMoving", true);
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
        }`
  
    }
}




The reference I am using is this video from youtube  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_Hn5ZsUIXM&t=552s
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it is really appreciated. I will attempt at adding this on. Let's see what the outcome is. Will give feedback. Again thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary bool variable that is false at the beginning of the Update loop and is set to true when a button assosiated with movement is pressed.

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 5.0f;
    private bool isMoving;


    private Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        speed = 5.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isMoving = false;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            isMoving = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        { 
            transform.Translate(-1 * Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            isMoving = true;
        }

        animator.SetBool("IsMoving", isMoving);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { 
            transform.Rotate(0, -1, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 1, 0);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I unfortunately get this error now not sure what I am doing wrong  Assets\PlayerControllertest.cs(21,10): error CS0111: Type 'PlayerController' already defines a member called 'Update' with the same parameter types

Comment: @BBatz07 you probably have two `Update` functions